# How to add jQuery to html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried this:

```
<script src="js/jQuery.js"type="text/JavaScript"></script>
```

Then I tried to call a click function on my button:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    function jfn1(){
      $("jbtn").fadetoggle()
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Where  is `jfn1` called? Where is the click?

Comment: Did you have a `<button type=button onclick="jfn1()">click me</button>`?  There's not enough information here other than make a wild guess and what you've done / tried to do as your text "I tried to call a click function" doesn't match the limited code you've provided.  Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to do, eg "run some code when I click a button" so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but with the code below, clicking on the button with class 'jbtn' will make it fade out.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.jbtn').click(function() {
    $( this ).fadeToggle();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="jbtn">Hey!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Chisom.

**All you did was define that function, you didn't actually call it.** Also it needs to be "*fadeToggle*", not "*fadetoggle*".

```js
  /**
   * Define function to fade button in/out
   */
  function jfn1 () {
    $("jbtn").fadeToggle() // "fadeToggle", not "fadetoggle"
  }

  /**
   * On document ready (DOM loaded)
   */
  $(document).ready(function (){
    // Call function on document ready
    jfn1()
  })
```

This will call "fadeToggle" when the DOM tree is loaded. **If you want to call it when clicked, it needs to look like this:**

```js
  /**
   * On document ready (DOM loaded)
   */
  $(document).ready(function (){
    // On button clicked
    $("jbtn").click(function () {
      // "this" is the function context
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
      $(this).fadeToggle()  
    });
  })
```

Also `$("jbtn")` will only find HTML elements that look like this: `<jtbn>...</jtbn>`. If you want to refer to a class (`<HTML_ELEMENT class="jtbn"></HTML_ELEMENT>...`), you should prefix it with a dot like this: `$(".jbtn")`.

Good luck!